# is it possible to give priority to write more then read in disks

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, kernel, performance

we have `hadoop` cluster , with data-nodes machines that have `HDFS` file system

we want to give more write to disks priority then read to disks

we read the - Using the Deadline IO Scheduler ( https://access.redhat.com/solutions/32376 )

but not clearly how to use this configuration (`Deadline IO Scheduler`) in order to give more `write` priority then `read` ?

Or maybe there are other kernel configuration ?

That can helps us with this question